# Python 3.3 ID3 reader

Tags: python-3.3, id3, id3-tag

I've tried many different ways to read ID3 tags but none of them seem to work due to the fact that they all to only work on python 2. Does anyone know a simple ID3 tag reader and writer, preferibly one that could do both, it would be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Stagger. It is implemented using Python3

https://code.google.com/p/stagger/

Source: http://id3.org/Implementations

Comment: Can you add a link to a tutorial?